# Is it possible today using a browser (Safari & chrome) to record video on mobile natively (android and iOS) and get their directory and reference it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, video, safari

I have a react JS app (mainly for Safari and Chrome), I want to know if it is possible today to record a video on devices (android and iOS) native camera. Get the directory of the recorded file from the file system and referenced later for use in the app.

Comment: I don't know about stuff like `react-native`, which has access to native methods, but this definitely won't be allowed on regular web apps. Browsers aren't allowed access to the device's file system, for obvious security reasons

Comment: While you can access the camera through the browser, file system paths are usually abstracted away because there is rarely if ever a legitimate reason a site would need them.

Comment: File System API is a thing.  While it's not widely used I don't see how I can make it work

Comment: There is a method of screen recording, google js record screen, but you would have to let the user download it by clicking a button, using an invisible iframe(google it) and it will show in downloads manager.